# (Functional) Spring cloud stream custom partition key implementation for publishing list of messages to single Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have created an application which uses Function based Spring cloud stream library to publish list of messages to single Kafka topic. I want to know how can we set partition key for each message in the list. Basically , each message should have its own partition key logic. Currently, it doesn't publish if I write custom `partitionKeyExtractor`. Let me know if anyone solved this issue before. For example:

```
Function<Message<String, List<Message<String>> processor(NotificationProcessor notification) {
return notification::processNotification
}
```